# How to change screen resolution on linux via jenkins?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I use jenkins for remote testing.
I create environmental variable and export display to linux machine running this cod in job configure

```
Xvfb :99 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

Now I want to change screen resolution there. I have try `xrandr -s 1280x800` but it doesn't work.
How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution to add Jenkins plugin 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

`Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0, 1680x1050x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99`

Solve the problem